# Investing money 101

Tags: banking, investing, investment-strategies, money-market

I feel really bad for posting this because I'm completly unable to make a proper search about my question. There is a very high chance that this is more than duplicate, and I apologize.

I would like to invest some of my money (about 10.000€) in a company that is already up and running (since 1996) and is already worth quite a lot of money.

I have absolutly no idea on the risks, the duties/rights, the things to know, to avoid, etc. I really don't know what to ask, I'm looking for information and advice. I'm just a regular guy an this is a lot of money, but I feel it is a good investment nonetheless. I would just like to know what I'm getting into as much as I can.

I've already contacted the company itself saying pretty much the same thing, and my bank. I'm expecting their answers to be different and yours to be more neutral.

Please know that I'm from belgium and that I am 25 years old, and that I currently have a job and a half, if that's relevant. Money income is reliable is what I meant.

I was thinking of investing in actions (because I don't know if there are even other ways to invest) and what it really means for me, the company, the bank, and my future.

I'm expecting to take my money back in about 10 years, considering how the flow goes. If they tend to go bankrupt I'm guessing I'll take it earlier, I'm not that misinformed.

Alright, if you have any question please ask in the comments, I want to make sure you have as much information as you need so you can help me better.

And thank you a lot for your time. I'll be on stackoverflow returning the favour if you have any programming question :D

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking.  What sort of information are you looking for?  Are you asking if this is a good idea?  Or are you asking how to do it given that you've already decided it's a good idea?

Comment: Are they a private company, or traded on a stock exchange?

Comment: p.s. You might use the words "stocks" or "shares" for English, instead of "actions" (which I understand to be from French).

Comment: "If they tend to go bankrupt I'm guessing I'll take it earlier" If they go bankrupt, you won't get your money back AT ALL, most likely.

Comment: @BrenBarn Right now I'm THINKING it's a good idea, but I feel like my lack of knowledge fogs my understanding of the idea itself and therefore if it's good or not.
But considering I think it's a good idea then I probably asking more "how should I proceed/how to do it".
That being said, basic information and general rules or guidelines are most welcome if you have any link or something to enlighten me in that area. I'm sorry about all this I'm really trying to be as clear as possible. I'm also really looking for advice.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea The company is Amazon, for what it's worth I guess it's just better not to play shy. So your answer should be, to my knowledge, a private company. I'm gonna sound really dumb but my idea is : **I'd like to give them money and see it grow with their company, which I belive is growing rapidly.**
Knowing that, maybe re-reading my question will be clearer

Comment: The way you invest a small amount of money in a large public company is to buy and hold shares of their stock.

Comment: Amazon? That is not a private company. While Amazon may be in the *private sector*, it is not a *private company* because it has shares listed on a public stock exchange that investors can purchase through a broker. A *private company* is a company where the ownership is private; there are no shares listed on a stock exchange that just anybody can buy.

Comment: Okay so this already explains why I can find it in the stock "market".
The simplest manner to achieve what I'm asking would be to buy shares for the amount of money of my willing, basically? For example, one share of X euros and "that's it" ?

Comment: You'll need to purchase shares through a broker. However, I suggest you learn a lot more about stocks and the stock market and investing before you proceed.

Comment: Can you suggest a link or something "easy" enough ? Or should I just buy "stock exchange for dummies" ? :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to invest money in a company is to buy its shares, or derivatives of its shares. However, it seems you're way in over your head. Don't buy what you don't understand.

There is plenty of material to teach you about stock investing on the internet. However, a book may be the fastest way to learn what you need to know. And yes, there is a "for dummies" book about that: [Stock Investing ForDummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/stock-investing-for-dummies-cheat-sheet.html). I just found it by Googling, I'm sure you can find even more interesting books out there.

(Note, the link is to the "cheat sheet" in the back of the book. The full book is worth reading.)

Comment: @Zil Yes, before proceeding please definitely read at *least* one book (preferably 5) about investing in US stocks.

Comment: Yes. One point I forgot to add was that it's probably a better idea for a Belgian to buy shares of a Belgian company. Trade what you know well. Invest in a company of which you could visit the premises.

Comment: In additional to stocks, there are also various types of corporate bonds.